# Railsのモデルで共通部分をまとめる方法を教えてください。

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubymine

Ruby on Railsで開発をしています。IDEはRubyMineを使ってます。

10個以上のモデルの中、3つのモデルだけモデル名を変更する必要があり、
テーブル名と違って、テーブルとの連携のためモデルには

```
def self.table_name_prefix
  'm_'
end
```

このようなメソッドを持っています。（３つのモデルに対応するテーブルは全部モデル名の前に「m_」をつけているようになっています。）
同じメソッドを持っているからこれを共通的にまとめて簡単にしたいんです。
ですが、まだRails初心者なので、どうすればいいかよくわかりません。
どうすればきれいに取りまとめることができるのか教えていただきたいんです！

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ActiveSupport::Concernを使ってみました。
こんな感じでどうでしょうか？
User, Item, Orderの3つのクラスがあり、UserとItemはテーブル名に"m_"というprefixが付く設計です。

```
# db/schema.rb
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20151230050425) do

  create_table "m_items", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  create_table "m_users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  create_table "orders", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.integer  "item_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  add_index "orders", ["item_id"], name: "index_orders_on_item_id"
  add_index "orders", ["user_id"], name: "index_orders_on_user_id"

end

# app/models/concerns/master_table_prefix.rb
module MasterTablePrefix
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  module ClassMethods
    def table_name_prefix
      'm_'
    end
  end
end

# app/models/user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  include MasterTablePrefix

  has_many :orders
end

# app/models/item.rb
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  include MasterTablePrefix

  has_many :orders
end

# app/models/order.rb
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :item
end
```

以下は動作確認用のテストコードです。

```
# test/models/order_test.rb
require 'test_helper'

class OrderTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  test "Create order" do
    user = User.create! name: 'Alice'
    item = Item.create! name: 'MacBook'
    order = Order.create! user: user, item: item

    assert_equal order, Order.first
  end
end
```

GitHubにもコードをアップしているので参考にしてみてください。

[JunichiIto/module-prefix-sandbox](https://github.com/JunichiIto/module-prefix-sandbox)

Answer (score 0):

実装の共有はモジュールを使うのが選択肢の一つかと思います。例えば`models/concerns`にモジュールを作り、それをモデルクラスで`extend`するのはどうでしょうか？(特異メソッドの定義になるので、`include`ではなく`extend`になる)

```
-- app/models/concerns/hoge.rb --
module TblnamePrefix
  def table_name_prefix
    'm_'
  end
end

-- app/models/hoo.rb --
require 'hoge'
class Hoo < ActiveRecord::Base
  extend TblnamePrefix
end

(irbでの実行例)
irb(main):003:0> Hoo.table_name_prefix
=> "m_"
```

Comment: require hoge が抜けてたので足しました。

Comment: このコードは期待した動作になりませんよ。```def self.xxx```のselfは```TblnamePrefix```を指すので、クラスでincludeしたところでクラスメソッドになるわけではありません。つまり、Hoo.table_name_prefixはNoMethodErrorになります。さらにrails4はconcerns内のファイルをautoloadするので```require 'hoge'```も不要なはずですよ。

Comment: 追記です。このケースではNoMethodErrorにならないですね。元々モデルにあるtable_name_prefixが呼び出されるので、空文字""が返ってきます。

Comment: `self.`の部分が抜けて検証していました。修正します。ちなみに良くは分かってないのですが、`require`をしないと、上の例で言うと`uninitialized constant Hoo::TblnamePrefix`と出てきてしまう(`rails c -s`で確認したときにそのような動作をした)ので強引に`require`して名前解決しているといった次第です。他に何か間違えたのかもしれませんが。

Comment: @cul8er:回答、ありがとうございます。試してみましたが、できませんでした。「m_」がなく、モデルの複数型のままでした。

Answer (score 0):

直接の回答ではないのですが、これぐらいだと必要なモデルに直接書いておいた方がいいのではないでしょうか。

たとえば、複数のモデルに

```
validate_presence_of :name
```

が共通して存在するからと言って、それを共通化することは普通はやりません。`table_name_prefix`も設定の一部であると考えると、共通化して隠蔽するには適さない内容だと思います。

すべてのモデルに共通しているなら共通化しても良いかもしれません。また、その3つのモデルに他と明らかに違う特徴があり、それをモジュールなり継承なりで表現できるのであれば、それは共通化の理由になります。

---

とは言っても、`def table_name_prefix; 'm_'; end`というのはみっともないので、gem作りました。

Gemfileに

```
gem 'table_prefix'
```

を追加して`bundle install`してください。

モデルでは

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  def table_name_prefix
    'm_'
  end
end
```

の替わりに

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  table_prefix 'm_'
end
```

と書けるようになります。

`table_prefix`は`table_name_prefix`メソッドを定義するメソッドになっています

```
module TablePrefix
  def table_prefix(prefix)
    class_eval { class << self; self; end }.class_eval do
      define_method('table_name_prefix') do
        prefix.to_s
      end
    end
  end
end
ActiveRecord::Base.extend TablePrefix
```